# Database performance analysis based on parameters

Tags: oracle

I have an Oracle(10.2.0.5) database and collected few performance parameters as below

```
Buffer Nowait %:    99.92   Redo NoWait %:  100.00
Buffer Hit %:   91.53   In-memory Sort %:   100.00
Library Hit %:  95.74   Soft Parse %:   96.68
Execute to Parse %: 31.75   Latch Hit %:    99.79
Parse CPU to Parse Elapsd %:    29.85   % Non-Parse CPU:    98.34
```

But I'm not sure how to interpret the data and come up with problemtic areas and recommendations.

Any suggestions please?

Comment: Each one of those metrics is a big subject in itself. I would look at resources such as Tom Kyte's asktom site, or Jonathan Lewis.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to tune a database by just looking at some key performance figures. I suggest to do some analysis for each of these parameters to get a brief understanding about their meaning.

I would start with these parameters:

```
Buffer Hit% 91.53
```

This seems to be low. OLTP systems I'm working with have a buffer hit rate around 99%.
In general this means, your database cashe doesn't contains the data you want to read and therefore you have to read the blocks from your disk.

```
Execute to Parse %: 31.75
```

This seems to be low too. Again a value around 99% is achievable. This parameter means, the database is parsing statements very often.

```
Parse CPU to Parse Elapsd %: 29.85
```

At best this figure is 100%. The value means the database spends 1 second CPU time for parsing and 3.35 seconds for waiting on something / somebody else.

I can't tell you whether these are really serious problems and how to solve them. These parameters are at least a starting point for further analysis.

Some ideas why your key performance figures are low:

- Shared memory is too small
- Statements are using bad execution plans (e.g. do full table scans)
- Statements are created dynamically instead of using prepared statements
- There is concurrency on the library and or dictionary cache

If you have a stats pack report, then another good starting point for further analysis are the "Top 5 Timed Events".

Comment: The buffer cache hit ratio is pretty well discredited as a guide to system performance. 99% is easily achievable by writing poorly performing SQL that relies over-much on indexes, and 91% could well be a good number for this system. Looking at top SQL statements is a better approach, but unfortunately the easiest way, AWR, is a pricey option.

Comment: Yes, you are true, an AWR report would help a lot. I haven't mentioned it, because it's not for free. If for example no bind variables are used, the top statements may be misleading but most probably you will see some of these statements.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't understand those metrics how are you going to manage your recommendations?  If we tell you, you need to double your server's memory allocation what will you do?  Go to your boss and tell them, " Some random bloke on StackOverflow said we need to buy more RAM?"  Or will you not mention SO?  In which case how do you intend answering your bosses next question, which will be "Why?".  Or perhaps, "I've got a lot money in the kitty, do you suggest we *triple* our RAM?"  Pretending to expertise is a slippery slope.

Anyway, solving performance problems by attempt to tune the entire server is a notoriously tricky and unreliable practice.  If you really want to solve performance problems ask your users which are the operation which bother them the most.  These might not be the long running queries: if a query takes two seconds but it is run 30000 times a day, shaving half a second off its elapsed time will be a major boon to your users.  Plus, it's easier to tune a single query than a whole database.